# Show button when div is overflowed - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div with text inside of it, when text is longer then 4 lines, I display just part of it with "..." at the end.

I want to detect div overflow and show "Show all" button next to it.
Is it any nice and simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: no, there is no easy way to do this, you have to go vanilajs and calculate boundes and then show or hide the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the characters of the text with `yourString.length` and if the length is bigger than, say 120 characters for example, then you add the show all button to the end of the string in html like `yourString += '<a onclick="doWhatever()">Show more</a>`